# Point in polygon algorithm that handles polygons that straddle the antemeridian

Tags: geospatial

I have a database of polygon points as latitude, longitude pairs and I need to test if a given lat,lng point is inside any of the polygons.

There are several algorithms around including [these](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/insidepoly/) but they don't work if the polygon straddles the antemeridian (off the coast of New Zealand, where longitude flips from +180 degrees East to -180 degrees West).

One solution I see is to detect if the polygon straddles the antemeridian and if so split it into two polygons, one on each side, then check each of them.

Answer (score 2):

The other (simpler) option, IMO, is to just test for that special case, and if it exists, apply a transform to your query point and the polygon.  For example, if it spans the anti-meridian, just translate everything by a specific longitude amount to make it not span the meridian, and do your standard test.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably overkill, but you might considering using spherical polygons instead of treating the map as a plane.  Here's a [library](http://geospatialmethods.org/spheres/) in Java that handles them and can do point-in-spherical-polygon checks.  Although, if you have polygons that contain more than half of the globe, or both poles, you might have issues since the definition of the enclosed area starts to break down.

Comment: Agreed--best is to treat them as spherical polys.  However, the enclosed area is always ambiguous unless you follow a winding convention (i.e. define inside as the area enclosed by a CCW traversal).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make all longitude coordinates 'move' to positive side of the GW meridian by adding 360? eg: the coordinate is -178degrees then becomes +182degrees, -1deg becomes 359deg, 1 deg becomes 361 etc...

I don't know how that will affect poles, but it would probably work fine for anything that doesn't touch the poles.

Comment: I don't have comment everywhere priviledge, so making an answer is the only way to get my say out...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. In the end the polygon I'm testing against is a rectangle so if it straddles the antemeridian (it has longitudes of different signs) chop it into two polygons, one on each side and query for objects that intersect either of them.